# Three.js jagged edges even with FXAA shader and anti aliasing

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render a cube in the center of my scene with white edges that rotates. I got this to work but the edges of the cube are very jagged when it moves.

I tried enabling anti-aliasing and adding a FXAA shader but the lines are still jagged.

I'm using [this FXAA shader](https://github.com/mattdesl/three-shader-fxaa) and react-three-fiber instead of vanilla Three.js.

This is my effects composer:

```py
const Effects = ({ factor }) => {
  const composer = useRef();
  const {
    scene, gl, size, camera,
  } = useThree();
  useEffect(() => void composer.current.setSize(size.width, size.height), [size]);
  useRender(({ gl }) => void ((gl.autoClear = true), composer.current.render()), true);
  return (
    <effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
      <renderPass attachArray="passes" scene={scene} camera={camera} />
      <shaderPass
        attachArray="passes"
        args={[fxaa()]}
        material-uniforms-resolution-value={[1 / size.width, 1 / size.height]}
        renderToScreen
      />
    </effectComposer>
  );
};
```

[Image here of the top edge of my cube with anti aliasing and FXAA applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78A5N.png)

Comment: This looks like there may be a mismatch between the size of your WebGLRenderer and the actual dimensions of your canvas.

Do you have a resize handler controlling the size of your renderer?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? `material-uniforms-resolution-value={[1 / size.width, 1 / size.height]}`.... The size you are sending doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: @manthrax It should already resize automatically from the library I believe. But I added in a listener manually to resize it and there wasn't any changes.

Comment: @2pha [The docs for the library](https://github.com/drcmda/react-three-fiber) says its the bounds of the view, correct me if it's wrong I copied this line from one of the shader examples there.

Comment: Piggybacking on what @2pha mentioned: Looking here:
https://github.com/mattdesl/three-shader-fxaa
It appears that the resolution uniform expects just width and height?

Comment: After tweaking those numbers I still couldn't get the edges to be smooth. I ended up not using LineSegments to draw my edges and instead using the LineMaterial method from the [fat lines example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat_wireframe.html) which worked well. Updating my post with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using LineSegments to draw my edges and instead using the LineMaterial method from the fat lines example, which has the added benefit of variable line width.

In case anyone comes across this and is wondering how to use edges with LineMaterial here is the code:

```
const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry.current);
    const geo = new LineSegmentsGeometry().fromEdgesGeometry(edges);
    const matLine = new LineMaterial({
      color: 'white',
      linewidth: 2,
      dashed: false,
    });
    matLine.resolution.set(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    const wireframe = new Wireframe(geo, matLine);
    wireframe.computeLineDistances();
    wireframe.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(wireframe);
```